# Entire sidebar disappears after going to next page and then using the browser Back button

Tags: bug

Just verified in IE 11, Chrome 50, and Firefox 46:

After logging in, I am on the Home tab. I can see the sidebar. I scroll to the bottom and hit "Next" and I am taken to page 2. I can still see the sidebar.

I hit the browser back arrow, and it takes me back to the first page but the sidebar is now completely blank as seen here:

[image: tada]

I have seen numerous reports of this happening on iOS and OSX Safari, but nothing related to the other browsers or a Windows platform.